# How to add Search bar in ( tabs plus visual force) communities

Tags: community, configuration, search

I have one  tabs plus visualforce community i want to show search bar in the community but i didn't find any configuration or setting. is there any way to enable like sale force classic search bar.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is [THIS](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_custom_search_box.htm&type=5) the one you are looking for? We also have a [TRAILHEAD](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/comm_search_basics/comm_search_basics_tailor) for this. Regards.

Comment: hi as i mention i'am using basic community visual force + tab not using nepali or any other .

Answer (score 0):

just need to enable chatter here is the documentation

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_search_behavior.htm&type=5